# Create a branch from a tag with maven

Tags: svn, maven-2, branch

I develop in trunk and periodically tag "stable releases" with the maven release plugin. For example:

`/trunk is MyProject 1.1-SNAPSHOT`

creates the stable release

`/tags/MyProject-1.1`

Works fine, no problems, just perfect.

Sometimes I have to deploy a hotfix but the trunk isn't ready, yet. So I need a branch from the last stable tag. Can maven help me here? Currently I copy the tag to the new branch location 
`/branches/MyProject-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT` and update the versions with `mvn versions:set`

Answer (score 10):

> So I need a branch from the last stable tag. Can maven help me here?

The Maven Release Plugin and its `release:branch` can help. Check out the tag and create a branch from the tag:

> By default, the POM in the new branch
>   keeps the same version as the local
>   working copy, and the local POM is
>   incremented to the next revision. If
>   you want to update versions in the new
>   branch and not in the working copy,
>   run:
>
> ```
> mvn release:branch -DbranchName=my-branch -DupdateBranchVersions=true -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false
> ```
>
> **Note:** This can be useful if you want
>   to create a branch from a tag
>
> #### Specify versions on the command line
>
> You may want to specify the versions
>   to use on the command line. This can
>   be useful for example if you are
>   running the release in non-interactive
>   mode. The branch goal can use the same
>   properties used by the prepare goal
>   for specifying the versions to be
>   used.
>
> ```
> mvn --batch-mode release:branch -DbranchName=my-branch-1.2 -Dproject.rel.org.myCompany:projectA=1.2 \
>      -Dproject.dev.org.myCompany:projectA=2.0-SNAPSHOT
> ```
>
> In this example, the POM in the new
>   branch will be set to the version
>   1.2-SNAPSHOT, and the local POM will be set to the version 2.0-SNAPSHOT.

#### Resources

- Maven Release Plugin Examples

  - [Create a Branch](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html)

Comment: If I check out the latest stable release, for example `svn co repo/tags/MyProject-1.1` I get a folder MyProject-1.1. If I convert the working copy to a branch `MyProject-1.1-SNAPSHOT`, where do I have to specify the new version? I'm sure maven didn't ask me for it (which is strange because it works fine with release:prepare)

Comment: @pascal-thivent , do you know if this works, `mvn release:branch -DbranchName=${project.version}` as seen at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910586/maven-pom-variables-as-command-argument)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a standard project in svn with trunk/tags/branches structure:

```
MyProject
   \trunk
   \branches
       \theOldBranch
   \tags
       \MyProject-1.1
       \MyProject-1.2
       \MyProject-1.3
```

You should

mvn release:branch -DbranchName=theNewBranchFrom12 -DupdateBranchVersions=true -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false -Dtag=MyProject-1.2

After that you should see MyProject\branches\theNewBranchFrom12 with pom files modified according to what you suggested when release:branch was executed.