# Maven pom variables as command argument

Tags: maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I want to be able to do something like:

```
mvn release:branch -DbranchName=${project.version}
```

I'm sure this won't work and I'm asking for help on how to achieve it. mvn release:branch require a branchName. I need the branchName on the command line argument taking the project version as value. My pom looks like this:

```
<profile>
          <id>branch</id>
          <activation>
            <property>
              <name>branchName</name>
            </property>
          </activation>
          <build>
            <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                  <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}-beta</tagNameFormat>
                  <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                  <suppressCommitBeforeBranch>true</suppressCommitBeforeBranch>
                  <remoteTagging>false</remoteTagging>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
            </plugins>
          </build>
      </profile>
```

This profile is triggerred only when branchName is present on the command line argument.

I appreciate your help.

**Edit: updated pom**

```
<profile>
          <id>branch</id>
          <build>
            <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                  <branchName>@{project.version}</branchName>
                  <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}-beta</tagNameFormat>
                  <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                  <suppressCommitBeforeBranch>true</suppressCommitBeforeBranch>
                  <remoteTagging>false</remoteTagging>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
            </plugins>
          </build>
      </profile>
```

Comment: why do you think you possibly refer to `${project.version}` before `mvn` has even read the `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The correct way to activate a profile is:

Remove the `<activation>` stanza and in your case do

```
mvn release:branch -P branch
```

This is all you should need given that you have hard coded `${project.version}` in the configuration anyway.

#### There is no way to get `${project.version}` without running the `mvn` command to begin with or parsing the `pom.xml` externally.

#### The [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html) on this is pretty clear:

> To create a branch execute this command:

```
mvn release:branch -DbranchName=my-branch
```

> By default, the POM in the new branch keeps the same version as the
>   local working copy, and the local POM is incremented to the next
>   revision. If you want to update versions in the new branch and not in
>   the working copy, run:

```
mvn release:branch -DbranchName=my-branch -DupdateBranchVersions=true -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false
```

Comment: Thanks. I simply did this: `mvn release:branch -P branch` . see edit above.